# How to automatically close the snack bar in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have implemented a snack bar when the user logs in he/she will get a notification from the snack bar whether the login was successful or unsuccessful. In my implementation, the snack bar appears the user can click dismiss and the snack bar will disappear. How do I auto close the snack bar?

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.isLoggedInError = true;
    // console.log(this.username);
    this.userService.login(this.username, this.password)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.isLoggedInError = false;
        // console.log("HERE IS THE res")
        // console.log(res.token);
        // this.logInresponsePayload = res;
        // localStorage.setItem('username', res.username);
        localStorage.setItem('userToken', res.token);

        localStorage.setItem('userRoles', res.roles_list);
        // this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        // console.log(res.token);

        // console.log(res.status_code);

        // Add ROLES : Predefine roles  add check 
        if (res.token === null ) {
          const  message = 'Wrong credentials provided!';
          this.snackbar.open(message, 'Dismiss');
          // this.router.navigate(['/']);

          // this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        } else {
          // console.log("print 200")
          const msg = 'Login successfull!';
          this.snackbar.open(msg, 'Dismiss');
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }

        // localStorage.setItem('apps', res.apps);


      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.isLoggedInError = false;
        }
      );

  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either set the duration for [each snack bar separately](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#dismissal) or set [global configuration defaults](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#setting-the-global-configuration-defaults):

```
// Single snack bar
snackbar.open('Message archived', 'Undo', {
  duration: 3000
});

// Global settings in app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 2500}}
  ]
})
```

[Also good to know](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#dismissal):

> Only one snack-bar can ever be opened at one time. If a new snackbar
>   is opened while a previous message is still showing, the older message
>   will be automatically dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

```
snackbar.open(msg, '', {
  duration: 1000
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to add a duration:

```
  this._snackBar.open(message, 'Dismiss', {
  duration: 2000,
});
```

In this case, it will close after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use duration: you can see it here:

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#dismissal